# Set req query output to a variable

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, registry, variable-assignment

I want to get the output of the command below assigned to a variable.

```bash
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_05E3&PID_0608\
```

If I run it from the Command Prompt, I get

> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_05E3&PID_0608\5&1d69168d&0&3
> ```

which is what I need to use for a `reg add`, so, I am trying to assign it to a variable.

For testing, I wrote this batch script:

```bash
FOR /F "delims=" %%g IN ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_05E3&PID_0608\') do (SET RegPath=%%g)
echo %RegPath%
pause
```

But, the only output I get is the current directory - `C:\Users\myname\etc`.

My final goal is something like this:

```bash
FOR /F "delims=" %%g IN ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_05E3&PID_0608\') do (SET RegPath=%%g)

reg add %RegPath%\Device Parameters /v EnhancedPowerManagementEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

I know this should be simple, what am I missing?

Comment: you forgot a `"`  - voted to close as typo.

Comment: You do not need to specifically define a variable, when the value is already assigned to one! It's a simple one line batch file command: ```@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_05E3&PID_0608" 2^>NUL') Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "%%G\Device Parameters" /V "EnhancedPowerManagementEnabled" /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F 1>NUL```.